# Describing all functions from a given relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to use mathematical notation to describe a set of all the functions from subsets of a relation.  Does anyone know how to describe this?  I'm having some difficulty and appreciate guidance.

Start with all relations between $X \times Y$, using power set:

$R \in P(X \times Y)$

The condition that a relation is functional:

$\forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y, \forall z \in Y, ((x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in R) \implies y = z$

Create a set $A$ of all the functional relations:
$A = \{ R : \forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y, \forall z \in Y, ((x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in R) \implies y = z \}$

Comment: Sure... that's fine.  It isn't generally necessary however since we have standard notation to describe this, the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ is notated as $Y^X$.  It is fine to go through the extra effort to define the set of functions in full words at least once, but you'll almost never have reason to do so ever again.

Comment: For the record, there is another notation for the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ that you may encounter in set-theoretic contexts: ${{^X}Y}$. It is also standard, though less common than $Y^X$.

Comment: There is no $Z$; I took the liberty to correct it to $Y$

Answer (score 0):

You seem to say (in te title e.g.) you want the function to be a subset of the given relation $R$. If you allow partial functions (so for some $x \in X$ there are *no* $y \in Y$ with $(x,y)$ in the function), I would then formulate it with an extra variable $f$ to express that :

$$\{f \in P(X \times Y)\mid f \subseteq R \land \left( \forall x \in X: \forall y_1,y_2 \in Y: ((x,y_1) \in f \land (x,y_2) \in f) \to (y_1=y_2)\right)\}$$

to define the set of all partial function that are subset of $R$.

Your expression is fine for all partial functions from $X$ to $Y$. It's a special case with $R=X \times Y$, you could say.

You can add the clause $\forall x \in X: \exists y \in Y: (x,y) \in f$ if you want functions with domain $X$.

Comment: Is the subset operation required?  $A = \{ R : R \in P(X \times Y) \land (\forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y, \forall z \in Y, ((x,y) \in R \land (x,z) \in R) \implies y = z) \}$

Comment: @Nick that’s if they don’t have to be a subset of $R$, like I said.